# How to show a Juniper interface bandwidth usage?

Tags: juniper, juniper-ex

I want to check a Juniper Switch's port bandwidth usage.

I tried show interfaces, but there is no current bandwidth condition:

```
admin@Juniper-ex3300-48t# run show interfaces ge-0/1/1
Physical interface: ge-0/1/1, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Interface index: 281, SNMP ifIndex: 717
  Link-level type: Ethernet, MTU: 1514, MRU: 0, Speed: 1000mbps, Duplex: Full-Duplex, BPDU Error: None,
  MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled, Source filtering: Disabled, Flow control: Enabled,
  Auto-negotiation: Enabled, Remote fault: Online, Media type: Fiber
  Device flags   : Present Running
  Interface flags: SNMP-Traps Internal: 0x4000
  Link flags     : None
  CoS queues     : 8 supported, 8 maximum usable queues
  Current address: 54:e0:32:fb:a8:74, Hardware address: 54:e0:32:fb:a8:74
  Last flapped   : 2019-08-08 02:30:04 CST (6w4d 10:08 ago)
  Input rate     : 656 bps (1 pps)
  Output rate    : 656 bps (1 pps)
  Active alarms  : None
  Active defects : None
  Interface transmit statistics: Disabled

  Logical interface ge-0/1/1.0 (Index 72) (SNMP ifIndex 718)
    Flags: Up SNMP-Traps 0x40004000 Encapsulation: ENET2
    Input packets : 2281844
    Output packets: 15936
    Protocol eth-switch
      Flags: Trunk-Mode
```

there only have the `Input rate/Output rate`.

The Juniper version is:

```
admin@Juniper-ex3300-48t# run show version
fpc0:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hostname: Z179-B-GW
Model: ex3300-48t
Junos: 14.1X53-D49.1
JUNOS EX  Software Suite [14.1X53-D49.1]
JUNOS FIPS mode utilities [14.1X53-D49.1]
JUNOS Online Documentation [14.1X53-D49.1]
JUNOS EX 3300 Software Suite [14.1X53-D49.1]
JUNOS Web Management Platform Package [14.1X53-D49.1]
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the command:

```
show interfaces ge-0/1/1 extensive | match bps
```

then you can get what you want, it should be like this:

```
>show interfaces ge-0/1/1 extensive | match bps
  Link-level type: Ethernet, MTU: 1514, MRU: 0, Speed: 1000mbps, Duplex: Full-Duplex, BPDU Error: None,
   Input  bytes  :          17080147150                 1824 bps
   Output bytes  :         128119082354                 4112 bps
        Link mode: Full-duplex, Flow control: Symmetric, Remote fault: OK, Link partner Speed: 1000 Mbps
                              %            bps     %           usec
     Input  bytes  :                    0                    0 bps
     Output bytes  :                    0                    0 bps
```

Answer (score 0):

Monitor Interface ge-0/1/1

This will let you monitor interface statistics in real time.